# Minimum value of normalized quadratic form of non-symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Let $M$ be an $n$ by $n$ real matrix (not necessarily symmetric), suppose $M$ is positive definite in that for any real vector $x \neq 0$, $x^\top M x > 0$. I'm wondering if $\min_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^\top M x}{x^\top x}$ has anything to do with the eigenvalues of $M$.

If $M$ is symmetric, I think it's the minimum eigenvalue. In general, I think it's about the relationship between the eigenvalues of $M$ and $M+M^\top$, this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52578/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-and-its-transpose-aat seems relevant.

Comment: @Surb But I failed to figure out the relationship between the eigenvalues of $M$ and $M+M^\top$

Comment: @Surb I'm a bit worried about the counter example given by DS in the post I linked

Comment: if $N$ is a large real number, how do the eigenvalues of $$ \left(  \begin{array}{cc} 1&N \\ -N & 1 \end{array} \right) $$  compare with those of the identity matrix?

Comment: It can be shown that $x\neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $M+M^T$ if and only if $\nabla \frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}=0$. By writing down the equations (i.e. computing the gradient) you will be able to establish an explicit relationship between the critical values of  $\frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}$ and the eigenvalues of $M+M^T$.